# how to test a auto format date function using selenium

Tags: jquery, date, testing, selenium, automation

I have a date field that accepts date in dd-mmm-yy format.But application can accept date in any format and converts it to the dd-mmm-yy format. How can I test this in selenium. As I tried by entering date in any format and then click somewhere on the screen as we usually do manually but selenium seems to be not accepting that click. Any idea how can I test this auto date format function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger the blur event using Javascript through Selenium API:

```
@Test
public void triggerBlurEvent() {
    driver.get("http://your-page.com");
    //yourfield.sendKeys("2013-06-04");
    assertThat("Selenium driver should be an instance of JavascriptExecutor", 
         driver, instanceOf(JavascriptExecutor.class));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$('#your-date-field-id').blur();");
}
```

Notice the very last line is actually using a jquery selector `$('#your-date-field-id')` to find your date field and it's triggering `blur` using javascript. Change that selector to match your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please guide how to write this in selenium RC.